# Submitting an update before the original version is released?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, app-store

I have version 1.0.0 of an app approved but not yet live; the release date is two weeks out. I also have some enhancements queued up as v1.0.1 but not submitted for review yet. The most important thing is that the app goes live on the scheduled date (synchronized to a marketing plan, external partner requirements, etc.) but if possible I would like to have my v1.0.1 available for the initial release.

If I submit my 1.0.1 version for review will it risk my ability to put the existing approved version live on time?

I see two risks:

- v1.0.1 is still in review, can I edit the release date (if necessary) and have v1.0.0 go live
- v1.0.1 is rejected for some reason, is v1.0.0 still available to go live?

UPDATE:

Our live date was pushed out due to business issues and we had plenty of time to get the update through review but in any case this is what we did:

- set the release date to the appropriate date
- submit the new version for review with version release control so it wouldn't go live until we pushed it after review

During the whole review process we were still able to edit the release date for the original version so I believe that it would have gone live if needed while the update was under review.

Answer (score 2):

Here's something you can try. I have done this for quite a few apps long back (about an 9 months back, not sure if things have changed)

Release the existing app and then immediately take it out of sale from all countries (you can do this on iTunes connect).

So technically you have your app on sale, and you'll be able to upload a new binary as an update.

If the update/1.0.1 gets approved in time, release it. If not approved, enable the 1.0.0 app for sale in the countries you want to sell.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The release date is two weeks out. I suggest you update the app. The process takes only around a week, even if it is rejected. You will be able to release v.1.0.0.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if v1.0.0 can go live even while v1.0.1 is under review? The new version isn't quite ready to go and probably won't be signed off until the release date is ~1 week away.

Comment: haven't really done something like this...but i do believe this is possible..i have retagged your question to generate more views..someone experienced in this might come along..